# How can I use define/contract (or something equivalent) in Typed Racket?

Tags: racket, contract, typed-racket

I am writing a function that accepts only positive numbers, and I want to ensure that it is used correctly both inside the module and elsewhere.

I wanted to write

```
#lang typed/racket
(require racket/contract)

(: excited-logarithm (-> Number Number))
(define/contract (excited-logarithm ([x : Number]) : Number)
  (-> (>=/c 0) number?)
  (displayln "Hold on to your decimals, we're going in!")
  (log x))
```

but Typed Racket doesn't provide its own `define/contract`, and vanilla `define/contract` doesn't understand Typed Racket's annotations (it throws a syntax error).

Can I work around this somehow? Can I use bare `contract` to attach a contract to `excited-logarithm` the way `define/contract` would?

Moreover, is there a good reason I *shouldn't* be doing this? Is mixing contracts and types discouraged?

*Note: I suppose what I really want here is dependent typing, but that's not available in Racket.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer here: use the type "Nonnegative-Real", or one of the other similar TR Types that capture this idea.

[http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html?q=Positive-Real#%28form._%28%28lib.*typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types..rkt%29.*.Positive-.Real%29%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html?q=Positive-Real#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types..rkt%29._.Positive-.Real%29%29)

(There are also refinement types, but you don't need them, here.)

Comment: Wow, I missed these in the reference, thanks! The question does remain for the general case, however.

Comment: It depends on how general your "general" case is. You can use refinement types to capture some constraints like this, and you can certainly define your own simple flat-contract macro to perform this check; most of the interesting/challenging parts of contracts happen for function types.

Comment: What are "refinement types"? I searched for that term in the Typed Racket docs and didn't find anything.

Comment: For the general case where a specific type does not exist, [intersection types](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._~e2~88~a9%29%29) might be a possibility.

Comment: @ssdecontrol It's an "experimental feature" in 6.10. Here's the URL for the docs: https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Experimental_Features.html?q=refinement#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._.Refinement%29%29